# App Indexing Not working and no error reported in Google Search console

Tags: android, google-search, android-app-indexing

I have implemented app indexing for the below app on play store 4 days before

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tcs.chicagomarathon2013&hl=en

I have followed all the steps till site verification and tested all my deep links and app URIs everything is working fine. But I am not able to see my app on Google search results.

Website linked : https://www.chicagomarathon.com

I have followed the same steps for other apps and they are working fine, any idea about this strange behavior or anything else I should do to make it working ?

**Update**
As requested

I have followed all the steps here
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app

My Manifest is perfectly find because all deep links are working like charm.

All app URIs added on webpages are tested with

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test

But Google Search results not showing the App anywhere linked with search result URLs.

You can view the source of webpages for app URIs for confirmation.

Comment: I can see the app in store. Is the issue still ocurring?

Comment: Yes nothing coming on search results , and no debugging no reports , no errors in search console.

Comment: This is most disappointed tool and feature I found in Google products .

Comment: Go to your developer console, and check if the application is correctly published. There are tutorials on how to checklist each step. And to say it again. I can see the app, and when I search for the keywords, it appeared. WHAT is the issue you are having?

Comment: If I search "Chicago marathon ", I should see the App with URL and install button which is how app Indexing works but nothing appearing on search results

Comment: Test it: https://www.google.com.br/?q=chicago+marathon+app

Comment: Yes I agree , search is fine but app Indexing not working. If you will search Chicago Marathon app it will show because of playstore search not because of app Indexing

Comment: Edit your question, post your AndroidManifest.xml, along with [the guide or whatever you used](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/introduction) to comply with the service.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Update , just now everything started working surprising awesome. Seems it took 10 days to get it reflected .

Comment: How were you able to confirm that it works? I am facing a similar issue where I am not able to confirm if indexing is working.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information about your implementation?

I suggest you to test your implementation using Fetch as Google (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en).

Let me know if you find something new.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have deep-link results working on your website. See the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot with App Indexing results]

Remeber to install the application from Google Play (not over adb), log into Chrome with the same account and then you should see the results.

Please use Search Console to discover more improvements that could be done to improve your implementation.